# ChangePage not working in jquery.mobile-1.4.3/jquery v1.11.1

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have two pages
1) page1.html
2.) page2.html
Now on button click inside page1, I want to load page2.
$.mobile.changePage("page2.html") giving "Error Loading page" error.

Have anyone faced this issue. What am i doing wrong

Tried something like this below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
swithchPage = function()
{
    //save data in local storage to get those in page2.html
    //Switch to page2
    $.mobile.changePage("Page2.html"); //throwing error "Error Loading page"
}

<!--Code snippet in Page1.html from where the page change takes place-->

<a href="#" data-role="button" style="left:auto" data-ajax="false" data-icon="grid" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" onclick="swithchPage()">Test Switch</a>
```

Comment: Without code we can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you test in on localhost without server?

Comment: REGENT...tried in Chrome, IE.. but no luck... android also showing the same error msg

Comment: Java_User .. thx..updated the post with some code